# AmbiguousStepDefinitionsException being thrown for two similar step definitions in Cucumber

Tags: cucumber, gherkin, ambiguous, cucumber-java

I am currently experiencing a `AmbiguousStepDefinitionsException` being thrown when trying to run Cucumber tests. This has confused me because from what I understand, using `$` at the end of a step definition should avoid ambiguity. Please correct me if I'm wrong.

For what I am testing, I want two different steps like this, so that I can easily append different parameters onto the initial `^I perform a type '(.+)' authorisation for (\d+) with (.+)$` step where appropriate.

These are the two step definitions that are causing the issue:

`^I perform a type '(.+)' authorisation for (\d+) with (.+) and (.+) merchant type$`

`^I perform a type '(.+)' authorisation for (\d+) with (.+)$`

Comment: The last (.+) in the second stepdef regex will also pickup the last part off the  first stepdef - "(.+) and (.+) merchant type". You can try ending the second one with some word like 'only' etc.

Answer (score 0):

`AmbiguousStepDefinitionsException` is thrown when there are two mappings that matches the same step.

You want to rephrase your mappings (and therefore steps) to make them unique.