# Disambiguating Cucumber step definitions

Tags: python, cucumber, gherkin

General question: is there a way to disambiguate two Cucumber step definitions where step definition A is a strict prefix of B?

For example, I have the following Cucumber step definitions written in Python:

```
@given(u'the Ambient Temperature is {degrees}')
...
@given(u'the Ambient Temperature is {degrees} higher than {setpoint}')
...
```

This results in an `Exception Ambiguous Step` error, which doesn't exactly surprise me.

I could re-word one of the two, but it would be useful to know: is there idiomatically correct way to dis-ambiguate these two step definitions, perhaps without resorting to regular expressions?

NOTE: This is essentially the same question as [AmbiguousStepDefinitionsException being thrown for two similar step definitions in Cucumber](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47873928/ambiguousstepdefinitionsexception-being-thrown-for-two-similar-step-definitions), but that question is using RegExps and -- besides -- it never got a real answer.

Comment: Looks like what ever regex is used for `{degrees}` also matches regular text. Maybe make it a bit more specific?